# How to get the FPS from a JavaFX scene?

Tags: performance, javafx, benchmarking, scene

I am currently writing a small graphical performance test benchmark for JavaFX.

Thus, I need to get the current FPS at which the JavaFX scene is being refreshed.

So far, I haven't found a solution how to accomplish this.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of event that I could use in order to get the FPS?

Comment: Needs a fps and/or a framerate tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific event that gives a frame rate. This reference/example might help.  It shows the frame rate when running  --  [JavaFX FPS Meter](http://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_fps_meter) .    It has a link to [source code](http://code.google.com/p/javafxdemos/source/browse/#hg/JavaFXFPSMeter/src/javafxfpsmeter/).